# TCP packet transfer when sender and receiver are same system

Tags: networking, tcp

I am running server and client in same system. TCP protocol is used for communication between them. In a scenario where client wants to send packet to server, will it go through network infra (i.e. router, internet etc) and come to server or will it manage transfer within system and ignore network.

Comment: The routing table in a host will send directly to an address in the same host. There have been many questions about how to get around that, but it really is not practical.